# Detect collision between a CCSprite and a CCMotionStreak

Tags: box2d, collision-detection, ccsprite

I have a CCSprite with a Box2d body attached. I'm doing this because my CCSprite is an irregular shape. I did this based on http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone.

However, the tutorial is based on collision for 2 sprites. I need to detect collision between a CCMotionStreak and a CCSprite. The CCMotionStreak is similar to a laser. I want to know when the laser hits the sprite.

I have googled but did not find anything useful. Does anybody know how I should approach this? 
Thanks in advance!